# Excel list based on conditions in another book

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

I need to create a list of names based on associated dates from another book.

For example, say a list of people need a car by a certain date, and I have a list of cars and the dates they are available, how can I generate a list of all the cars that will be available for each person?

**customer**

[image]

**cars**

[image]

**Final output**

[image]

It does not need to be presented as I have shown, thats just the idea.

It would be even better if following on the list could break down and say "car available 7 months in advance" , "car available 6 months in advance" etc.

Comment: Have you looked into TEXTJOIN and FILTER ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula

=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER($F$2:$F$5,$G$2:$G$5<=B2,"No Car Available"))

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you! I am not familiar with TEXTJOIN. one more question if possible. If I add cars to my list with no associated date they are still being listed. For example, adding in Car 6 with no date will list it as available for all people. What can I do to update this so that ONLY cars with dates will be listed. I have tried several different things but no luck so far

Comment: @chris22 Yes it works. because Car 5 or Car 6 has no date meaning its falling under the less then the criteria date.